# Is there a way to display command line to another user

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, batch, cmd.exe

We are two colleagues working on a program running on windows VPS.
Sometimes we both connect to the VPS using separate users through RDC.

As our project is launched through CMD by an Administrator user,
only one of us can see it at a time.

Is there is a way to see the same instance of CMD instance in
different users or somehow share its logs?

Comment: You need Windows Server for that.

Comment: @harrymc They mention VPS (Virtual Private Server) and Windows, so one could assume they are using Windows Server. In addition, regular windows would not allow 2 people to work on the same computer using different users at the same time anyway. That said, I have no idea how to do this using Windows Server though... Care to write up an answer? I think this is what OP wants anyway, and its definitely something I can learn from regardless. :)

Comment: @LPChip: Done .

Answer (score 2):

Sharing files between two users is possible, if both users have enough permissions
on the folder.

If you wish to have a look at another user's session and desktop,
this is called "shadowing the session" and is available on Windows Server.
You may access your colleague's session as read-only, or as controller,
and with or without his permission, as is determined
by the options you have set for Terminal Server.

For more information about shadowing sessions, see the article
[How to Shadow (Remote Control) a User RDP session on RDS Windows Server 2016 / 2012 R2](http://woshub.com/rds-shadow-how-to-connect-to-a-user-session-in-windows-server-2012-r2/).

Another possibility is if your colleague is running a VNC remote-control product,
then you could join his session/desktop as viewer or a participant.
The best known product here is [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/),
but there are [many others](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=remote+desktop),
commercial and free.
When choosing one such free product, ensure that it is also free on
Windows Server and the conditions of use.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. (+1 of course)